# What are the possible values for contentURL when using Kik iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, kik

I'm trying to send a message via Kik from my iOS app, and I use official [Kik SDK](https://github.com/kikinteractive/kik-api-iphone) for that.
Specifically, the message should contain URL/link for the certain app on the Apple's app store.

This is the code:

```
    KikMessage *message = [KikMessage articleMessageWithTitle:@"Title of your Article"
                                                         text:@"Check it out!"
                                                   contentURL:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idXXXX?mt=8"
                                                   previewURL:@""];
    [[KikClient sharedInstance] sendKikMessage:message];
```

It works to the moment I try to open URL I've sent. For some URLs (ex: `@"http://google.com"` it works good - it opens a pop-up with the appropriate content of that page.

But if change it to `@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idXXXX?mt=8"`, Kik shows the error:

> Unknown Content
>   No action associated with this content

Changing protocol to `http` and to `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXX` doesn't help either.

I'm wondering if there are any requirements for that URL or its content, any restrictions on it? Is it possible to send user a link to the app store?

ps: it probably doesn't matter, but despite the docs, previewURL is not optional - it cannot be nil, and the empty string is passed, as a workaround.